# Mysterious ">s" showing up in HTML

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know why this mysterious ">s" is showing up above the table in this fiddle? It's not in the HTML.

```
<table>...</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d2j3x5xh/

Comment: Well this should be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: this question was answered fairly quickly and easily, so I'm not sure why it's on hold and down-voted.

Comment: It's on hold because it's not a good format for this site. It's completely domain specific to you. It's a simple typographical error, that is unlikely to assist anyone in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line 234 - There is an extra `>` after the comment end

Line 274 - There is an `s` after the closing `</tr>`

Comment: Adding to that, the reason why the text appears at the top of the page is that HTML moves all content outside of a table cell up to before the table.

Comment: Thank you!.  and @Brian, thanks for the additional explanation.  Always good to know why things appear the way they do.

Answer (score 1):

2 reasons:

You have an extra ">" on line 234, after the comented-out "Bowling Green" line. You have an extra "s" on line 274, after the closing `</tr>` for Baltimore, MD.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code I found a line saying

```
  <!--<td> Bowling Green, KY </td -->>
```

You have an additional `>`.

Same thing goes for the `s`. Just delete or comment out lines until you have isolated the problem.